# Crash/bug in ask question screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

To reproduce this issue:

Don't input anything inside Ask question screen and click on Preview button, app will crash.

Comment: Confirmed on version 0.1.40

Comment: No repo on 0.1.39.

Comment: Yes its in 0.1.40 build.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in version 0.1.41, thanks!